# How can I show the database record on click on the thumbnail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

[image]
[image]

I have a thumbnail:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="cash">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
            <p><%= book.price %> <img class="azn" src="<%= asset_path('azn.png') %>" alt=""></p>
        </div>
        <%= image_tag(book.image) %>
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <% @book_id = book.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'id', @book_id %> # I saved ID here for searching later
    </div>
<% end %>
```

On click on the these thumbs opens another  with the information from the database record:

```
book_title, book_author etc.
```

How can I get all these info from the database by ID on clik?

I wrote a function in Cover.rb model:

```
def self.book_info(id)
    Cover.where(id: id).select('book_title')
end
```

So, how can I use it on click on the thumbnail div and get book_title for the this book with AJAX?

Comment: Why not using data attributes for this small piece of information? Then use jQuery to display it where you might need it.

Comment: So what, you already load these objects (books), so accessing their attributes and put them into data-attributes will not make it any worse. Well, this is what I would do probably. But it's your choice.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 how can I realize it?

Comment: Put a screenshot of what your feature should do, from your description is a little bit hard to understand where exactly the information about the book should appear.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 I was added the images. On click on the first image thumbs opens the second image with the info on the same page ($('.somediv').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your `thumbnail` div will have all the data stored in data attributes (I'll show with only a few attributes):

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-author="<%= book.author %>" data-year="<%= book.year %>" data-price="<%= book.price %>"></div>
```

this will generate something like this (based on each book information):

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-author="Jaroslav Gashek" data-year="1989" data-price="3"></div>
```

now I assume you'll use a modal window that will popup and that can be called with js code

`$(#my_modal).show();`

like bootstrap-modal does. But before opening the modal you need to replace the information in the modal placeholders with the one from selected book based on data attributes:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );

  // when all info is updated you open the modal
  $(#my_modal).show();
});
```

You'll need your modal to be available on the page (that will be hidden) and appear only when user clicks on a book and information in modal is updated. Modal should have the below code in order to make the above script to work properly.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_modal">
  <div class="author"></div>
  <div class="year"></div>
  <div class="price"></div>
</div>
```

a kind of working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4sya4jz/1/

Important! The modal should not be repeated as many books you have in your page, it will be only one that will be updated with new info as user clicks on a different book.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

In View

```
<img class="azn" src="<%= asset_path('azn.png') %>" alt="" onclick="bookInfo(#{book.id})">
```

In JS

```
  function bookInfo(bookId) {

       $.get('/books/get_book_info?id=' + bookId)
      }
```

In Controller

```
 class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def get_book_info
     @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end

 end
```

now in app/books/get_book_info.js.erb

```
   $('#some div').html("<p><%= j @book.book_title %></p><p><%= j @book.book_title %></p>")
```

should have `book_title` and `book_author` attribute/column of Book model/books table.

Answer (score 0):

Write controller method which you can call on ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/controller method url",
  data: $(this).attr('data-id'),
}).success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

data-id is attribute of the element on which user will be clicking and it will hold the id of the record.

In success you will get data in the response and you can use it wherever required.